# How to modify on-the-fly kafka cluster logger?

Tags: security, apache-kafka, configuration

I have a secure kafka cluster (SSL with certificate) in production and i want to modify some logger level on-the-fly without restarting the cluster (even with a rolling update)

In the [official doc](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/dynamic-config.html#changing-broker-configurations-dynamically) it state you can modify broker configuration dynamically.

So, i tried this command

```
/bin/kafka-configs --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --entity-type broker-loggers --entity-name 1
```

only to obtain this error

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed.

If i try with port `9093` i get a `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kafka-configs` is the right command to use.

You need to tell the command "who you are" / "log in".

It's achieved with the `--command-config` option.

There is an [official example here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/dynamic-config.html#updating-ssl-trust-store-of-an-existing-listener)

```
kafka-configs --command-config /etc/kafka/client.properties --bootstrap-server [hostname]:9093 --describe --entity-type broker-loggers --entity-name 1
```

Once you can use `describe`, then you can `alter` like

```
kafka-configs --command-config /etc/kafka/client.properties --bootstrap-server [hostname]:9093 --alter --add-config "kafka.authorizer.logger=INFO" --entity-type broker-loggers --entity-name 1
```

Which result in

> Completed updating config for broker-logger 1.